# How can locals() be exploited in python code?

Tags: python, namespaces

I stumbled across the following warning when I was reading [Code Like a Pythonista: Idiomatic Python](http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html) by David Goodger.

> Excerpt from the article ...
>
> ```
> print('Hello %(name)s, you have %(messages)i messages' % locals())
> ```
>
> This is very powerful. With this, you
>   can do all the string formatting you
>   want without having to worry about
>   matching the interpolation values to
>   the template.
>
> **But power can be dangerous. "With great power comes great
>   responsibility." If you use the
>   `locals()` from with an
>   externally-supplied template string,
>   you expose your entire local namespace
>   to the caller. This is just something
>   to keep in mind.**

I am trying to understand the *specific scenarios* in which using `locals()` can be dangerous. Any examples of how the presence of `locals()` in a code can be exploited are appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple example: If you have some magic ultra important encryption key `enc_key` in your local namespace of a webapp-view and you would use a user supplied string in this way:

```
 a_var_that_gets_display = user_supplied_string % locals()
```

Than an attacker could pass something like `Encryption key is %(enc_key)s` as `user_supplied_string`and would get your key.

I admit that this a highly unlikely and constructed example. Generally using `locals()` is save as long as you don't use user supplied data as format string.

Answer (score 6):

Sample, trivial code:

```
script_name = 'readpw.py'
...
entered_pw = raw_input()
if entered_pw != real_pw:
    print "%(script_name)s: The password you entered: "+entered_pw+" is incorrect."%locals()
```

Consider the case where entered_pw is `%(real_pw)s`