# concatenate literal and number

Tags: python, list, printing, python-3.2

I have 3 sets of list and would like to do a simple print out using for loop in python v3.2

example:

```
q1 = ['a','b','c']
q2 = ['x','y','z']
q3 = ['red','blue','green']

print (q1)
print (q2)
print (q3)
```

Below is the result I would like and can achieve with the 3 print lines above

```
['a', 'b', 'c']
['x', 'y', 'z']
['red', 'blue', 'green']
```

However I would like to use a for loop e.g.

```
for i in range(0,3):
    i+=1
    print ('q'+str(i))
```

the above for loop will only print

```
q1
q2
q3
```

How can I concatenate and the 'q' and i and print out the actual lists. Thank you in advance to anyone who can help. Please note that I am not even up to the level of a novice! I have found many good examples, help from this site. Fab..

Answer (score 2):

Numbering variable names is usually a sign that those variables should be replaced by a list:

```
q = [['a','b','c'],
     ['x','y','z'],
     ['red','blue','green']]

for item in q:
    print(item)
```

You can access the object formerly called `q1` by now using `q[0]` (since Python uses 0-based indexing).

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over a tuple that contains the lists.

```
>>> q1 = ['a','b','c']
>>> q2 = ['x','y','z']
>>> q3 = ['red','blue','green']
>>> for x in q1, q2, q3: # (q1, q2, q3)
...     print(x)
...
['a', 'b', 'c']
['x', 'y', 'z']
['red', 'blue', 'green']
```

Answer (score 0):

For your information, you may use `locals` or `globals` to get variables by names for practice purposes:

```
In [62]: for i in range(1,4):
    ...:     print locals()['q'+str(i)]
    ...:     
['a', 'b', 'c']
['x', 'y', 'z']
['red', 'blue', 'green']
```

**Note** they [can be dangerous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585648/how-can-locals-be-exploited-in-python-code), you should refactor your code when you wanna do this.

Comment: You really shouldn't do this!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `eval`.

```
q1 = ['a','b','c']
q2 = ['x','y','z']
q3 = ['red','blue','green']

for i in range(0,3):
    i+=1
    print eval('q'+str(i))
```